# Format string with two digits

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am using the following:

```
'%.2f%.2f%.2f' % (hours, minutes, seconds)
>>> 0.00:0.00:2.00
```

How would I force two digits, but no decimal points, so it is:

```
>>> '00:01:18'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't use `f` when you really want `d`:

```
'%02d:%02d:%02d' % (hours, minutes, seconds)
```

`f` is for floating point values, `d` for integers. `02` zero-pads the values:

```
>>> hours, minutes, seconds = 1, 0, 42
>>> '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (hours, minutes, seconds)
'01:00:42'
```

You may also want to look into the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), a newer and more powerful syntax; the equivalent version is:

```
'{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Comment: See also: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Answer (score 3):

Why do work you don't have to? Rather than separate values, deal with a single [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#time-objects):

```
>>> from datetime import time
>>> h, m, s = 1, 2, 3
>>> t = time(h, m, s)
>>> str(t)
'01:02:03'
```